# Add a custom meta field value after the price on single products pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, meta-boxes

I have created a custom Metabox named "Info" on my product pages.
I would like to show the corresponding meta field value in the template **content-single-product.php** behind the product price. But it doesn't output the corresponding meta field value and this is not working.

[image: screenshot]

My problem is that I don't know how I can call the corresponding meta field value. Is it in **`function.php`** php file or in **`content-single-product.php`** template.

This is the code that I use to create the Metabox *(and it works)*:

```
// Create metabox
<?php
function meta_box1()
{
  add_meta_box('new_meta', 'info','new_meta_output','product');
}
add_action ('add_meta_boxes','meta_box1');


function new_meta_output($post)
{
  $new_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_new_meta',true);
  echo ('<label for="new_meta"> info meta box</label>');
  echo ('<input type="text" id="new_meta" name="new_meta" value="'.esc_attr($new_meta).'"/>');
}

function new_meta_save($post_id)
{
  $new_meta=sanitize_text_field($_POST['new_meta']);
  update_post_meta ($post_id,'_new_meta',$new_meta);
}
add_action('save_post','webtot_new_meta_save');

?>
```

This code is in function.php file of my theme folder **is not working**:

```
// add metabox to behind price product

function meta_product() {
    // don't show in product --problem
    $new_meta2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_new_meta',true);
    echo $new_meta2;

    // show in product
    echo "123456";
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meta_product',25);
```

What I am doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **UPDATE**
>
> 1) You are **NOT getting the Product ID** in your last function. For that you need to use WordPress **`get_the_ID()`** and the the data value will be outputted as desired.
>   2) Your function **`new_meta_save()`** has not the same name that in the  corresponding add_action *(hook)*.
>   3) All your code goes on `function.php` file located in your active theme.

Here is your revisited functional code:

```
// Creating a custom metabow in Admin Individual product pages
add_action ('add_meta_boxes','add_info_meta_box');
function add_info_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box('new_meta', 'info','info_meta_fields_output','product', 'side');
}


function info_meta_fields_output($post)
{
    $new_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_new_meta',true);
    echo ('<label for="new_meta"> info meta box</label>');
    echo ('<input type="text" id="new_meta" name="new_meta" value="'.esc_attr($new_meta).'"/>');
}

add_action('save_post','save_info_meta_box');
function save_info_meta_box($post_id)
{
    $new_meta=sanitize_text_field($_POST['new_meta']);
    update_post_meta ($post_id,'_new_meta',$new_meta);
}


// Displaying the value on single product pages
function meta_product($product_id) {

    $new_meta2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_new_meta', true);
    echo $new_meta2;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'meta_product',15);
```

*ALL the code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme or in any plugin file).*

This code is tested and works

---

To show this meta field value after the price you need a priority between **`10`** and **`20`**, (but if you want to show it before the price, after the title, the priority is going to be between **`5`** and **`10`**.

On the concerned template for **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** you have:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

Comment: thank LoicTheAztec, but my problem that metabox don't show in product. i know prority on woocommerce

Comment: @user142146 I have **UPDATED** my answer. **All is working** as you expected now (I have test it completely). Sorry but your question was not really clear; so first I didn't understand what was your problem. Thanks

Comment: Excellent, Thank LoicTheAztec.